Guys can someone help me to fix this I'm so newbie and I have no experience this. Happens when I'm installing lubuntu
Create a new partition (465.46 GiB, ext4) on '/dev/sda'  
Job: Create new partition on device '/dev/sda  
Command: sfdisk-force-append/dev/sda  
Command: sfdisk-list-output Device,UUID/dev/sda  
Job: Set the label on partition '/dev/sda2' to "lubuntu_2404"  
Command: sfdisk-part-label/dev/sda 2 lubuntu 2404  
Job: Create file system 'ext4' on partition /dev/sda2  
Command: mkfs.ext4-qF/dev/sda2  

Specs:
HP pavillion g6
CPU- i5 2nd gen
RAM- 2gb ddr3
HDD- toshiba something 512gb
GPU- and hd 7670m
It is a laptop btw
This is the error that's showing up installing up:
Installation Failed The installer failed to create partition on disk 'TOSHIBA MQ01ABD050'. 
Details: Create a new partition (465.46 GiB, ext4) on '/dev/sda' 
Job: Create new partition on device '/dev/sda   
Command: sfdisk-force-append/dev/sda   
Command: sfdisk-list-output Device,UUID/dev/sda   
Job: Set the label on partition '/dev/sda2' to "lubuntu_2404"   
Command: sfdisk-part-label/dev/sda 2 lubuntu 2404   
Job: Create file system 'ext4' on partition /dev/sda2   
Command: mkfs.ext4-qF/dev/sda2   

Every time I do it just shows this error no matter what what I do, I erase the entire disk replace partition or do what the option shows up there. I am booting from EFI using a USB pendrive (bootable) I made using Rufus. I can't create a partition manually either. I used Puppy Linux before, but I was not satisfied with it so I used Lubuntu.

I don't see any errors in that output.  What's your actual problem?

You want to install Lubuntu on that PC or from a live session, you just want to create partitions with sfdisk.

This reads like some kind of homework assignment.

This is the error thats showing up installing up--- Installation Falled
The installer failed to create partition on disk 'TOSHIBA MQ01ABD050'.
Details:
Create a new partition (465.46 GiB, ext4) on '/dev/sda'
Job: Create new partition on device '/dev/sda
Command: sfdisk-force-append/dev/sda
Command: sfdisk-list-output Device,UUID/dev/sda
Job: Set the label on partition '/dev/sda2' to "lubuntu_2404"
Command: sfdisk-part-label/dev/sda 2 lubuntu 2404
Job: Create file system 'ext4' on partition /dev/sda2
Command: mkfs.ext4-qF/dev/sda2

Everytime I do it just show this error no what what I do , i erase the entire disk replace partition or do what the option shows up there. I am booting from EFI using a USB pendrive (bootable) i made using Rufus. I cant create a partition manually too. I used  puppy linux before but was not satisfied with it so I used lubuntu

@PiKu from the installer disk can you open a command line and run sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda and show what it says as an edit to your post (or a picture)?  It's important to see all the SMART output to see if this is a hardware problem or a bad installer disk.  If it doesn't work on the command line run sudo apt update && sudo apt install smartmontools first on the command line with Internet access on the live environment so you can get the packages

I have done that smartmontools thing but it's showing this---  (copyright information here) /dev/sda: unknown USB bridge (0x03f0:0x5a07 (0x1100) please specify device type with he -d option use smartctl -h to get a usage summary

Maybe helpful - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/calamares-rare-failure-to-create-partition-mkfs-errors/2774

Start a live session of Lubuntu.
Once the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
  sudo apt install gparted
  sudo gparted

From gparted, select the hard drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new gpt partition table.
In the free space, create a 512-megabyte partition, Efi-Boot partition (Fat32).
Next, create a 60-gigabyte partition, ext4 system.
Create another 8-gigabyte partition, swap system.
Create another remaining partition that you plan to use for Linux, ext4 system.
Apply the changes, close gparted, close the terminal, start the installation, choose manual partitioning and select Grub on the hard drive, the 60-gigabyte partition for /, the 8-gigabyte partition for swap and the remaining one for /home. Continue with the installation.
